# Why is my Rails Form Helper not using the correct sub-hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I have a form to create instances of the BookingAccommodation model. This model belongs to an Accommodation and has a internal_name.

```
<%= form_with model: @booking_accommodation, url: property_settings_accommodations_type_booking_accommodations_path(@accommodation) do |f| %>
    <div class="flex flex-col">
        <%= f.label :internal_name %>
        <%= f.text_field :internal_name, class: "border" %>
    </div>
    
    <div>
        <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

```
class Property::Settings::Accommodations::BookingAccommodationsController < PropertyController
    def create
        @accommodation = Accommodation.find(params[:type_id])
        @booking_accommodation = @accommodation.booking_accommodations.new(booking_accommodation_params)

        if @booking_accommodation.save
            redirect_to edit_property_settings_accommodations_type_path(@accommodation)
        else
            # Handle error
        end
    end
    
    private

    def booking_accommodation_params
        params.require(:booking_accommodation).permit(:internal_name)
    end
end
```

The generated html of the text_field is as following:

```
<input class="border" type="text" name="internal_name" id="internal_name">
```

But this needs to have a booking_accommodation sub-hash like this:

```
<input class="border" type="text" name="booking_accommodation[internal_name]" id="internal_name">
```

If I don't have the sub-hash the params are not nested and the form results in an error. What is causing this?

Comment: The most likely reason is simply that `@booking_accommodation` is nil. Check it by adding a breakpoint.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The fact that you're showing the `create` method strongly suggests that you don't understand that it's the `new` method that initially renders a form, and therefore where you need to set your ivars.

Comment: I have a really strong suspicion that in this case there is no separate new route and that the form is "embedded" in the show view of the parent resource.

Comment: Could be, still the wrong place to be setting those ivars :)

Comment: In this case there is indeed no seperate new route and the form is embedded in the edit view of the Accommodation. But your comments did point me in the right direction. Adding the missing `@booking_accommodation = BookingAccommodation.new` in the view of the parent resource did fix my issue. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Nice to hear, well done.